# Dynamics AX: How to determine what is using Change Tracking?

Tags: sql-server, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, change-tracking

This is Dynamics AX 2012 R2 on SQL 2012 SP2.

I am trying to clean up our dynamics db, I notice we have Change Tracking enabled on 44 different tables.  I am not sure if these were enabled by default, or enabled for a specific reason after install.  I would like to disable CT if it's not being used at all, but I am not clear how to determine what is using it.

How can I determine if Dynamics AX app is using CT or not?  Here are the tables enabled:

```
AGREEMENTHEADEREXT_RU
BUDGETCYCLE
BUDGETMODEL
BUDGETPLANHEADER
BUDGETPLANLINE
BUDGETPLANNINGSTAGE
BUDGETPLANPRIORITY
BUDGETPLANSCENARIO
BUDGETSOURCE
BUDGETSOURCETRACKING
BUDGETSOURCETRACKINGDETAIL
BUDGETSOURCETRACKINGRELIEVINGDETAIL
BUDGETTRANSACTIONHEADER
BUDGETTRANSACTIONLINE
CUSTTABLE
DIMENSIONATTRIBUTE
DIMENSIONATTRIBUTEVALUE
DIMENSIONATTRIBUTEVALUECOMBINATION
DIMENSIONATTRIBUTEVALUETOTALLINGCRITERIA
DIMENSIONATTRVALUECOAOVERRIDE
DIMENSIONATTRVALUELEDGEROVERRIDE
DIMENSIONFINANCIALTAG
DIRPARTYTABLE
EXCHANGERATE
EXCHANGERATECURRENCYPAIR
EXCHANGERATETYPE
FISCALCALENDARPERIOD
FISCALCALENDARYEAR
GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY
GENERALJOURNALENTRY
GENERALJOURNALENTRY_W
HCMWORKER
LEDGER
LEDGERCOV
LEDGERENTRYJOURNAL
LEDGERFISCALCALENDARPERIOD
LEDGERJOURNALTABLE
LEDGERJOURNALTRANS
LEDGERVOUCHERTYPE_CN
MAINACCOUNT
MAINACCOUNTCATEGORY
OMHIERARCHYCHANGELOG
PROJTABLE
USERINFO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no specific *log* or similar mechanisms to determine what created change tracking.

As far as I know these modules enables change tracking:

- [Management Reporter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507082.aspx)
- [MDM (Master Data Management)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn720451.aspx)
- [AIF getChangedKeys](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh433529.aspx)

AX AIF Framework tracks enabled tables for Change Tracking in `AifSqlCdcEnabledTables`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM AifSqlCdcEnabledTables
```

See column `Scope`.

Comment: Thanks, what would be best way to check what was enabled out of the box?

Comment: @Greg check table `AifSqlCdcEnabledTables` in SQL